# How to write dd status/result message to a file?

Tags: command-line, pipe, dd, lubuntu

I use this `dd` command for checking disk speed:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/path/file bs=1G count=1 oflag=direct
```

which gives back something like this:

```
1 oflag=direct
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1,1 GB, 1,0 GiB) copied, 8,52315 s, 126 MB/s
```

Now I would like to pipe this output, not the file `dd` is writing, but to a separate file.

I tried adding

```
>> /tmp/foo
```

or

```
| sudo tee /tmp/foo
```

to the `dd` command, but that just creates an empty file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be able to insert `dd` in a pipeline before or after another command, its informational messages are written to standard error rather than to standard output.

[The OpenBSD manual for `dd`](http://man.openbsd.org/dd) explicitly mentions this (but [the Ubuntu manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/dd.1.html) seems to omit this fact, but mentions it in the more complete `info` page):

> When finished, `dd` displays the
>        number of complete and partial input and output blocks and truncated
>        input records to the **standard error output**.

To redirect standard error from a command, use `2>filename`.  To append the standard error stream to an already existing file without truncating it, use `2>>filename`.

For example:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/path/file bs=1G count=1 oflag=direct 2>dd.txt
```

---

Note that you mix appending output in the first of your examples (using `>>`) with truncating output in your second example (using `tee`). To append to a file with `tee`, use `tee -a`.

Comment: The manual of GNU `dd` is in the `info` page, the man page is just a dump of `dd --help` for convenience for people who are not used to `info` documentation and/or just want a quick reference with a pager. The bottom of the page will tell you where to look for the actual manual (where the writing to stderr is documented).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks, I added a short mentianing of that. I personally have never been a friend of the `info` system... :-/

Comment: Thanks for this clear and concise answer. Just to be clear: Using `tee` will not work in this case, because it does not read from `stderr`, correct?

Comment: @rookie_senior `dd ... 2>&1 | tee ...` would work.

Answer (score 3):

`dd` output is actually printing to `stderr` not `stdout`

You can redirect `stderr` to a file for your `dd` command as follows:

`$ dd if=/dev/zero of=/path/file bs=1G count=1 oflag=direct
 2>> /path/to/file`